# Using JPA 2.1 Converter with Java 1.8 Time API reults in Eclipse JPA-Error "The left and right expressions type must be of the same type"

Tags: eclipse, java-8, converters, jpql, jpa-2.1

I'm using Eclipe IDE Neon.2 working on a JavaEE 7 project (JPA 2.1 & Java 8).

In my Entities new Java 8 Time API  is used and therefore i need to use JPA-AttributeConverter to convert them to sql-datatypes. In most cases i want to use named queries with JPQL.

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = Account.QUERY_FIND_LOGGED_USER_TODAY, query = "SELECT a from Account a where a.lastLoggedInDate == CURRENT_DATE")
public class Account implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public final static String QUERY_FIND_LOGGED_USER_TODAY = "account_find_logged_user_today";

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateAttributeConverter.class)
    private LocalDate lastLoggedInDate;

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public LocalDate getLastLoggedInDate() {
        return this.lastLoggedInDate;
    }

    public void setLastLoggedInDate(LocalDate lastLoggedInDate) {
        this.lastLoggedInDate = lastLoggedInDate;
    }
}
```

The AttributeConverter looks like this

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
    }
}
```

Eclipse shows me an error-message pointing to "a.lastLoggedInDate == CURRENT_DATE" saying

> The left and right expressions type must be of the same type.

Is this a *real* JPA-Error, or does Eclipse-JPA-Validation not support the combination JPA-Converter & JPQL.